# JavaScript string with new line - but not using \n

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string that has new lines in. I am wanting to convert these to HTML `<br>`s, but I'm having a hard time detecting them.

Imagine a JavaScript string set like this:

```
var foo = "Bob
is
cool";
```

They are the kind of new lines that I need to detect. They aren't using the `\n` special character - they are just plain format.

Comment: That *is* `\n` (unless it's possibly also `\r`)

Comment: I think he meant that they're not expressed with the `\n` escape sequence, but rather that the character is literally there in the source code.

Comment: @Pointy: but the result would still be the same, provided this wasn't a syntax error.

Comment: "Plain format" newlines are simply the visible result of a \n special character. \n is just an alias of it.

Comment: @Evert yes I agree of course; I'm thinking syntax error too.

Comment: As of 2016 there is a way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40334713/1454514

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because javascript strings must be terminated before the next newline character (not a `\n` obviously). The reason `\n` exists is to allow developers an easy way to put the newline character (ASCII: 10) into their strings.

When you have a string which looks like this:

```
//Note lack of terminating double quote
var foo = "Bob
```

Your code will have a syntax error at that point and cease to run.

If you wish to have a string which spans multiple lines, you may insert a backslash character '`\`' just before you terminate the line, like so:

```
//Perfectly valid code
var foo = "Bob \
is \
cool.";
```

However that string will **not** contain `\n` characters in the positions where the string was broken into separate lines. The only way to insert a newline into a string is to insert a character with a value of 10, the easiest way of which is the `\n` escape character.

```
var foo = "Bob\nis\ncool.";
```

Comment: Aug 2016 Update: There is NOW a way to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40334713/1454514

Answer (score 90):

**UPDATE:** I just [came across](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805113/1454514) a wonderful syntax design in JavaScript-ES6 called [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Syntax). What you want to do can be literally be done using `` ` `` (backtick or grave accent character).

```
var foo = `Bob
is
cool`;
```

In which case, `foo === "Bob\nis\ncool"` is true.

Why the designers decided that `` ` ... ` `` can be left unterminated, but the `" ... "` and `' ... '` are illegal to have newline characters in them is beyond me.

Just be sure that the targeting browser supports ES6-specified Javascript implementation.

---

P.S. This syntax also supports a pretty cool feature that is present in PHP, .NET, and some other scripting languages; namely "[Tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals)" with which you can build a parameterized string like this:

```
var a = 'Hello', b = 'World';
console.log(`The computer says ${ a.toUpperCase() }, ${b}!`);
// results in "The computer says HELLO, World!"
```

Comment: I am trying to use `` in Google Apps script IDE and it says "Illegal character.". How to handle?

Comment: @kiki It seems that Google Apps _doesn't_ support ES6 syntax (the version of javascript that allows this),

Comment: @kiki so I suggest learning and using Babel in order to "transpile" ES6 to older versions of _compatible_ javascript for Google Apps scripts. You can also [ask a new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) question titled "How to use ES6 in Google Apps script IDE", maybe someone has a solution for it.

Comment: Can I give you 10 upvotes for the backtick answer? It really works like magic! :)

Comment: "Why the designers decided that ` ... ` can be left unterminated, but the " ... " and ' ... ' are illegal to have newline characters in them is beyond me."
 - 
The developers of Javascript in 1995 were not the same as the ones in 2015. And changing old-style strings would break old code. Pretty clear reasoning.

Comment: @JimmieTyrrell In hindsight, you're clearly correct.  I guess I'm more infuriated by the fact that they decided against changing the older syntax to avoid breaking old code as you put it, despite that " ... <newline> ... " and ' ... <newline> ... ' were still invalid syntax, so I wouldn't see  the point of not changing them to allow the same newline syntax.

Comment: best answer bro

Answer (score 9):

Check for `\n` or `\r` or `\r\n`.

There are several representations of newlines, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Comment: I'm doing that. I've checked for all three: `console.log(story.message.split(/\n/g));
     console.log(story.message.split(/\r/g));
     console.log(story.message.split(/\r\n/g));` They all return the same. No split.

Answer (score 4):

I think they using `\n` anyway even couse it not visible, or maybe they using `\r`. So just replace `\n` or `\r` with `<br/>`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you understand how \n works. The resulting string still just contains a byte with value 10. This is represented in javascript source code with \n.

The code snippet you posted doesn't actually work, but if it did, the newline *would* be equivalent to \n, unless it's a windows-style newline, in which case it would be \r\n. (but even that the replace would still work).

Comment: Thanks. In that case, why won't this work?  `console.log(story.message.split(/\n/g)); console.log(story.message.split(/\r/g)); console.log(story.message.split(/\r\n/g));` They all return the same. No split

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following function:

```
  function nl2br (str, is_xhtml) {
     var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
     return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
  }
```

like so:

```
var mystr="line\nanother line\nanother line";
mystr=nl2br(mystr);
alert(mystr);
```

this should alert `line<br>another line<br>another line`

the source of the function is from here: 
http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br:480

this imitates the `nl2br` function in php...

Answer (score 3):

This is a small adition to @Andrew Dunn's post above

Combining the 2 is possible to generate readable JS and matching output

```js
 var foo = "Bob\n\
    is\n\
    cool.\n\";
```

Answer (score 0):

The query string that I used to to escape the new line character in JS :
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Data.csv' INTO TABLE DEMO FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;`

This involves new ES6 syntax - Template Literals `` and I tried changing '\n' to '\r\n' and worked perfectly in my case.

PS: This example is my query to upload CSV data into mysql DB.