# Integrate style tag using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try to add the `<style type="text/css"></style>` to head using jquery.
I tried like this

```
 $("<style type='text/css'></style>").appendTo("head");
```

Previously, i have this type of

```
<style type="text/css">
img{ 
    -moz-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; 
    -webkit-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; 
}

@-moz-keyframes rotateRight{
    0%{ -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%; }
    100%{ -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateRight{
    0%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%; }
    100%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
</style>
```

That above style worked when I tried this with jquery like this:

```
$("<style type='text/css'>img{ 
    -moz-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; 
    -webkit-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; 
}

@-moz-keyframes rotateRight{
    0%{ -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%; }
    100%{ -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateRight{
    0%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%; }
    100%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }
}</style>").appendTo("head");
```

but i get error in editor itself. 
Here is the pic
[image]
I think i messup something :( 
http://jsfiddle.net/jSvUE/

Any suggestion would be great
Thanks,
vicky

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you doing this?

Comment: AFAIK you can't have actual new lines (enter-key-presses) in a Javascript string.  Either make it one line or dynamically load/enable a stylesheet using Javascript.

Take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10154554/382456

Comment: You can just add a `\\` (forward slash?) to the end of each line and try again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$("<style type='text/css'>img{ \
    -moz-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; \
    -webkit-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; \
} \
@-moz-keyframes rotateRight{ \
    0%{ -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%; } \
    100%{ -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); } \
} \
@-webkit-keyframes rotateRight{ \
    0%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%; } \
    100%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); } \
}</style>").appendTo("head");
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jSvUE/2/

**Really hackish**, but for a quick-n-dirty solution, that'll work.  The idea here is that you are **escaping the new line.**  A more elegant way to accomplish this, though, is to put that `img` as a class, and use http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ to toggle the animation.

**Update 2016**

Here in 2016, ES6 is widely supported, and the above hack can be replaced with this still-horrendous blob:

```
$(`<style type="text/css">
img {
    animation: 600ms rotateRight infinite linear;
}
@keyframes rotateRight {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: 50% 50% }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg) }
}
</style>`).appendTo("head");
```

Comment: That's what I said ;-)

Comment: Hah, yeah, I had already started writing the post before I saw your comment.

Comment: +1 Thanks I'm wondering why this should happen ;-) Any way i get a quick and working solution

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure why your doing this but your problem is you cant break lines in javascript try this

```
$("<style type='text/css'>img{-moz-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear;-webkit-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; }"+

"@-moz-keyframes rotateRight{0%{ -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%; }100%{ -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }}"+

"@-webkit-keyframes rotateRight{ 0%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%; } 100%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }}</style>").appendTo("head");
```

An example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UaSb5/) either stick everything on one line if it is a string. Or if you want to keep nice formatting break the line with +

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the line breaks in the JS. You can store the styles in a variable and then append that to the head so that the styles are re-usable:

```
var $styles = '<style type="text/css">img{-moz-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear;-webkit-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear;}@-moz-keyframes rotateRight{0%{ -moz-transform:rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%; }100%{ -moz-transform:rotate(360deg); }}@-webkit-keyframes rotateRight{0%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%; }100%{ -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg); }}</style>';

$("head").append($styles);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only valid way is string concatenation:

```
$("<style type='text/css'>img{ " +
" -moz-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; " +
" -webkit-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; " +
"}" + ...
).appendTo("head");
```

Please pay attention that it's not recommended to do something like this:

```
$("<style type='text/css'>img{ \
    -moz-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; \
    -webkit-animation:.6s rotateRight infinite linear; \
} \
...
```

> The whitespace at the beginning of each line can't be safely stripped
>   at compile time; whitespace after the slash will result in tricky
>   errors; and while most script engines support this, it is not part of
>   ECMAScript.

[Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Multiline_string_literals#Multiline_string_literals)