# how to get js to render newlines in rendered content using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/kQ3eJ/3/

```
var string = "This is a & string that has \n new lines in it\u0027s body";

//does not do the newline or unicode
document.getElementById("insertJavascript").innerHTML = string;

//does do the newline and unicode
document.getElementById("insertJavascriptWithPre").innerHTML = '<pre>' + string + '</pre>'; 

//but if i get the string from the HTML to begin with it doesn't work
var htmlString = document.getElementById("htmlWithNewline").textContent;
document.getElementById("insertJsHtmlWithNewline").textContent = htmlString;
```

basically the webpage has a element whose innerHTML has newlines in it (data from a JSON)
I want to format this data so it's more legible on the front end

As you can see in the fiddle - typing the newlines (\n) into javascript work, but if the newline is a part of a string that comes from the innerHTML, it does not get formatted correctly.

Is there a way to "unescape" the newlines in the string?

Okay so I tried to string replace the "\n" with "\n" and "\r" with "\r" and that seems to have worked

```
var what = htmlString.replace('\\n','\n');
// what = what.replace('\\u','\u');
what = what.replace('\\r','\r');
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = '<pre>' + what + '</pre>';
```

but it's failing on the unicode replace - I may have to replace the entire unicode block as one?

Comment: In simpler words, you want to replace the newline with  a break tag

Comment: no, that is not what I want to do, if you looked at the fiddle you'd see I want this to be in a <pre></pre>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it looks like JSON.parse() will unescape all the \n \r and \u and allow it to be formatted correctly in the `<pre></pre>` tags

```
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.parse('"' + htmlString + '"') + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `JSON.parse` for this. By default `Javascript` will consider the `\n` as new line.

Refer the following question.

[JavaScript string with new line - but not using \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154429/javascript-string-with-new-line-but-not-using-n)

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the fiddle? JS treats JS strings as newlines but if the string is pulled from a webpage via innerHTML it recognizes the newline as an escaped newline (literal \n)