# jQuery Mobile append string issues

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, google-chrome-devtools

What does it mean if you cannot expand a DOM node in the Chrome Elements view tool?

I have manually appended a very long string of html containing nested elements, but when I view the rendered page and examine the elements, only the first level element exists, with a ... for the text field.  When I try to expand the selection to see the inner contents, the closing tag for the only visible element goes away, and none of the contents appear visible.

Any ideas?  Malformed HTML?  I really don't think it's incorrectly formatted...
I am using jQuery Mobile for this.

EDIT:  Here is how I got the page to render what I wanted.

```
$('#myID').append( 
    '<li id="'+id+'" name="chat2" dsid="chat2_'+j+'" class="'+currentPage+'_chat2 ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-btn-up-a ui-first-child" data-icon="false">
       <div class="ui-li-static-container">
          <div class="'+currentPage+'_itemGrid2_wrapper" data-wrapper-for="itemGrid2" dsrefid="chat2" _idx="_'+j+'">
             <table id="'+currentPage+'_itemGrid2" class="'+currentPage+'_itemGrid2" dsid="itemGrid2" name="itemGrid2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
               <colgroup>
                  <col style="width:auto;">
                  <col style="width:172px;">
               </colgroup>
               <tbody>
                  <tr class="'+currentPage+'_itemGrid2_row_0">
                    <td id="'+currentPage+'_picCell2_'+j+'" name="picCell2" class="'+currentPage+'_picCell2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
                      <div class="cell-wrapper"><img class="'+currentPage+'_itemImage2"src="'+image+'" id="'+currentPage+'_itemImage2" dsid="itemImage2" name="itemImage2">
                      </div>
                   </td>
                   <td id="'+currentPage+'_Cell2_'+j+'" name="Cell2" class="'+currentPage+'_Cell2" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
                     <div class="cell-wrapper">
                       <div name="sellerName" id="'+currentPage+'_sellerName" dsid="sellerName" data-role="appery_label" class="messagePerson  '+currentPage+'_sellerName">'+sellerName+'</div>
                       <div name="lastMessage2" id="'+currentPage+'_lastMessage2" dsid="lastMessage2" data-role="appery_label" class="'+currentPage+'_lastMessage2">'+message+'</div>
                       <div name="productID2" id="'+currentPage+'_productID2" dsid="productID2" data-role="appery_label" class="'+currentPage+'_productID2">'+productID+'</div>
                       <div name="messageID2" id="'+currentPage+'_messageID2" dsid="messageID2" data-role="appery_label" class="'+currentPage+'_messageID2">'+messageID+'</div>
                     </div>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
      </div>
  </li>');
```

Figured I'de put the whole in there in case of syntax..

EDIT2:

The only reason I am doing this clunky solution is because I can't append a collapsed DOM js variable.

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.cache[0].length; i++){ 
  var div = Appery("chat1").clone(); 
  div.attr("id",currentPage+"_chat1_"+i); 
  div.find(Appery("messageID")).text(this.cache[0][i]._id); 
  div.find(Appery("buyerName")).text(this.cache[0][i].user_name); 
  div.find(Appery("productID")).text(this.cache[0][i].productID); 
  Appery("allChats1").append(div); 
}
```

Comment: are you sure it was appended as html? it might have just been appended as a text node

Comment: I appended a very long string in the format of html.  Is there a way to convert the string to the appropriate type?

Comment: appended how? javascript? show us how you're appending it

Comment: let me add that when I try to run jQuery.find("") on anything in this node it returns undefined.  But the page renders the node fine

Comment: that piece of code shouldn't even work as you can't have carriage returns (new lines) in a javascript string

Comment: @kennypu this was done to make it readable.. The actual string doesn't have carriage returns.  Also, are you sure about that because I tried \n after each tag already to see if it would do anything and it made no change... Perhaps I needed \\n to break it

Comment: \n is fine, just the actual character (pressing enter) will break. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154429/javascript-string-with-new-line-but-not-using-n

Comment: It's a good idea to check your console for JS errors...

Comment: what does the html string look like that you're passing in as a variable? I think I understand what you were saying earlier. Can you paste in your variable declaration expression?

Comment: @AlexNeigher I have uploaded the old (cleaner) solution that didn't append anything to the DOM

Comment: Where Appery('chat1') is equivalent to $('#chat1')

Comment: @bneigher, why are you calling .text() and not .value()? what type of DOM element is `div.find(Appery("messageID"))` targeting?

Comment: It is targeting an HTML5 label tag, and .text(1) modifies that value.  The find(1).text(1) logic indeed works, as selecting those modified values in this context successfully reflects the changes.