# How to convert a multiple line JSON string into a javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm working with Google's civic info API and I'm trying to figure out how to convert a JSON repsonse into a variable javascript object (we'll call that object civicInfoObject). Then I want to display to contents of that object onto the page with HTML. I'm new to javascript and haven't been able to successfully come up with a solution or find an answer.

It's a relative big project for me so I am working in bite-size pieces. I copied and pasted the JSON response to my query and created a new HTML document with it. So basically my goal right now is to store this static JSON string in a variable (civicInfoResponse), convert it into an object and store that in a variable (civicInfoObject), and then display the contents of that object onto a page with HTML.

Here is my strategy thus far:

```
var civicInfoResponse = "copy-and-pasted string
that spans
multiple lines"

var civicInfoObject = JSON.parse(civicInfoResponse);

document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = civicInfoObject;
```

Here is the fiddle I created so you can see the JSON response in its entirety: https://jsfiddle.net/km38o815/2/

The code I wrote might be completely wrong, I'm not sure. I'm having a hard time with my limited knowledge about javascript. Can anyone help me out or at least point me in the right direction? It would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: cant you just put civicInfoResponse into the innerHTML?  JSON.parse will give you a json object, but the innerhtml needs to be a string. also your fiddle wont work, you need to escape all those quotes.

Comment: @kmacdonald Not to be pedantic but `JSON.parse` returns an object. JSON is a string. Clarifying for anyone who might read this and think that JSON is an object.

Comment: Well, I could, but my next step is to loop through the object and output specific information (like the president's name), so I have to convert it into an object. But are the quotes what is causing the problem? Can I write a function to escape all the quotes so the string is read in its entirety? Thanks for the response by the way.

Comment: thanks for that clarification on JSON, Jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your fiddle.  If you have the JSON you should need quotes around it?  is this what you are looking for?

```
document.getElementById("Info").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(civicInfoResponse);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/km38o815/7/ oops this should work now.

Comment: The quotes are part of what is returned with the JSON response. That's part of the reason I'm having a hard time finding an answer to this question. Also, I'm not sure that solution works because the JSON is already a string, right?

Comment: Ohh, I see what you're saying. The innerHTML needs to be a string.

Comment: Thanks for that fiddle update, that's awesome. I can see my logic was a little flawed. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This question is related to: [JavaScript string with new line - but not using \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154429/javascript-string-with-new-line-but-not-using-n)

In other words, if you need the JSON to span multiple lines, use `\` before starting a new line:

```
var civicInfoResponse = "copy-and-pasted string \
that spans \
multiple lines"
```

`civicInfoResponse`should contain:

```
copy-and-pasted string that spans multiple lines
```