# String.raw equivalent in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, python, string, internet-explorer, templates

I am returning a DTML Template generated using Python's Zope and assigning it a JS variable by evaluating it in browser. My template would look like:

```
var html = <dtml-var "html">

# which is nothing but
var html = "<html>
<body>
Hello
</body>
</html>
"
```

This is not valid since Javascript expects double quotes to close before a newline character as explained in some questions like [JavaScript string with new line - but not using \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154429/javascript-string-with-new-line-but-not-using-n).

I figured that I could actually do:

```
var html = String.raw`<dtml-var "html">`
```

which works in Chrome, however `String.raw` doesn't exist in `IE 11`.
  Are there any alternatives that I can use?

Alternatively, can I fix this problem in Python by doing the below snippet? Are there any caveats to be aware of?

```
# Replace newline character to \n literally.
html.replace("\n",\\n")

# Escape the double quotes
html.replace("\n",\\n").replace("\"", "\\\"") i.e replace " with \"
```

Comment: why do you need `String.raw`? (it doesn't look like you do, it looks like you need template strings, which won't work in IE, ever). also, you can use `JSON.stringify()` to make literals from regular strings.

Comment: `String.raw` they say is for Templates so I used that and it worked. `JSON.stringify` is in Javascript right? I mean how do I get into JS from my database in the first place? Are you telling me to store differently? I store the HTML directly to database and retrieve it. There could be multiple solutions for this problem, but I am just thinking which approach would be good.

Comment: ohh, simply turn the string from the DB into JSON on the backend, and it arrives on the client as a valid JS string, even with line-breaks in the DB source string...

Comment: so you mean `var html = JSON.parse(jsonified);` i guess I need to understand what `JSON` is better :) if you realize I am also executing it.

Comment: yes, that should un-pack the string into a multi-line/quote-having string without issue.