# How to track a form submission using Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, event-tracking

I wanted to track a simple contact us form submission and the code I used for this is,

```
form action="/contact-us/#wpcf7-f2017-p2044-o1" method="post" **onsubmit = "ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form Submission', 'post', location.pathname, {
  nonInteraction: true});"** class="wpcf7-form sent" novalidate="novalidate"
```

It doesn't work and gives this error,

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  VM300:1

Everything else in the Google Analytic account is working fine. May be because the developer has implemented the code inside a function?

ny help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are these ** characters actually in the code, or did you try to highlight the bit with the event tracking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a newline character in your string

```
"ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form Submission', 'post', location.pathname, {
  nonInteraction: true});"
```

Removing it makes it work:

```
"ga('send', 'event', 'Contact Form Submission', 'post', location.pathname, {nonInteraction: true});"
```

The problem is explained here:
[JavaScript string with new line - but not using \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154429/javascript-string-with-new-line-but-not-using-n)

Comment: Thank you so much Elmer, I will try

Comment: thats it :) new line was the error thank you very much Elmer Fudd