# Appending newlines characters (i.e. \r\n) to a form field sent in a post request

Tags: javascript, html, http-post, newline, textinput

I'm writing some web forms which test servers written by students as an exercise. Some of the servers don't quite work to specification, as expected with class work. It would be useful to append a Windows new line character (i.e. `\r\n`) to a `POST` request generated by a browser, as some servers are doing a `ReadLine` rather than using the `Content-Length:` header count.

I'm looking at generating the following request (from IE):

```
POST /Brian HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-GB
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:43
Content-Length: 8
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

location
```

but appending a `\r\n` to the end. My attempt at doing this so far is:

```
<form> 
Username: <input type="text" name="url" id="url4"
    onChange="document.getElementById('update4').setAttribute('action', 
    'http://localhost:43/' + document.getElementById('url4').value);"> </input> 
</form>
<form id="update4" method="post" action="http://localhost:43/">
Location: <input type="text" name="isindex" id="location5" 
 onChange="document.getElementById('location5').value = 
             document.getElementById('location5').value + '\\\r\\\n'"> </input>
<input id="mysubmit3" type="submit" value="go" ></input>
</form>
```

I know that appending newlines to things can be tricky, so I'm looking for guidance. I don't want the newline characters encoded as part of the POST. I just want to send a raw `\r\n` after the `POST` command to flush the post through.

Comment: why are you escaping `\ ` in your string concat? Shouldn't `+ '\r\n'` work?

Comment: Do not believe `<input>` element has a `textarea` `type`? `d` should be lowercase at `document.getElementByID('location5')`

Comment: @JDHooper I saw in another SO answer (which I can't locate now) that some browsers strip the `\` and extra escapes are needed; but it fails either way!

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks. Those were typos that I missed. Fixing them does not make it functional

Comment: Updated question to clarify it a bit and correcting the typos made in error.

Comment: Hello good sir, I was wondering if you could accept the top voted answer. It will helpful to those that stumble on this post and are looking for answer to have more confidence in the answer. Thank you :D

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 If none of the answers here satisfy you, could you please [edit] your question to clarify what exactly you are looking for in an answer?

Answer (score 20):

Text input elements only allow single lines of text. Per the [W3C Working Draft for text input](https://w3c.github.io/html-reference/spec.html#input.text.attrs.type):

> #### input *type*=text – **text-input field**
>
> **type** = "text"
> Specifies that its input element is a one-line plain-text edit control for the input element’s [value](https://w3c.github.io/html-reference/spec.html#input.text.attrs.value).
>
> ...
>
> **value** = [string without line breaks](https://w3c.github.io/html-reference/spec.html#form.data.stringwithoutlinebreaks)
> Specifies a value for this input element.
> *value*: Any string that contains no line feed (U+000A, “LF”) or carriage return (U+000D, “CR”) characters.
>
> <sup>[1](https://w3c.github.io/html-reference/spec.html#input.text.attrs.type)</sup>

And per [the MDN documentation for `<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) where attribute *type* = 'text':

> |  **Type**  |  **Description**            |
> | -------- | --------------------------- |
> | [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) | The default value. A single-line text field. Line-breaks are automatically removed from the input value.|
> <sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#input_types)</sup>

So adding new line characters to the value of the text input element is basically superfluous.

Alternative solutions might include:

- adding a hidden text area and set the value of the text area to contain the value of the text field with the new line character, though it may be difficult to prevent students from un-hiding the  textarea and altering the value. See this demonstrated in [this phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/q3ex-g52y).
- use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to store the values of the form, add the new line characters and then submit the form using the formdata with that altered value. This may only work by having the form be submitted asynchronously (e.g. with AJAX, to a different target like an iframe, other window, etc.).

New lines can be added via JavaScript with a couple different techniques, including:

- new line characters: `\n`:

```js
console.log("Bob\nis\ncool");
```

- [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40334713/1575353))

```js
console.log(`Bob 
is 
cool.`);
```

- [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)()

```js
console.log('line 1'+String.fromCharCode(10, 13)+'line 2')
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120315/input.text.html#input.text</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input</sub>

Answer (score 4):

have you tried using an actual `textarea` and not type `textarea`?

also **getElementByID** is incorrect (the D isn't capitalized) and I fixed your escaping.

**instead of:**

```
<input type="textarea" name="isindex" id="location5" 
 onChange="document.getElementByID('location5').value = 
             document.getElementById('location5').value + '\\\r\\\n'"> </input>
```

**try this**

```html
<form> 
 Username: <input type="text" name="url" id="url4"
    onChange="document.getElementById('update4').setAttribute('action', 
    'http://localhost:43/' + document.getElementById('url4').value);"> </input> 
</form>
<form id="update4" method="post" action="http://localhost:43/">
Location: <textarea name="isindex" id="location5" 
 onChange="document.getElementById('location5').value = 
             document.getElementById('location5').value + '\r\n'"> </textarea>
<input id="mysubmit3" type="submit" value="go" ></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. I get: `isindex=location%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A`

Comment: are you using `input text` or an actual `textarea`? I wasn't aware that `input text` allowed new lines, but an actual `textarea` tag does.

Comment: I was using a `input text`. I am aware that `textarea` permits newlines, but it encodes them as part of the post. I want them to be unencoded; a real `\r` and not `%0D` and a real `\n` and not `%0A`. This is to overcome poor implementation of the servers I am testing; thus I have to break the HTTP spec...

Comment: have you tried a server side post like using php for example?

Comment: I mean have you tried running a script that sends posts instead of sending client side.