# How can new line be respected when updating content of a <pre> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, newline, pre

After seeing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10154554/1575353) I was trying to find a way to update the contents of a [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag and have the new-lines displayed using implicit new-lines (i.e. in the string literal). I tried setting various properties: *innerHTML*, *innerText*, *textContent*, *nodeValue* (after checking answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21311670/1575353)) yet none seemed to have the white-space preserved.

I am aware I could use [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) - e.g. `"Bob " + String.fromCharCode(10, 13) + "is "`... but wanted to find a way using the former syntax as well.

```js
//Perfectly valid code
var foo = "Bob \
is \
cool.";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('pre').textContent = foo;
});
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Is there a way to update the contents as desired?

Comment: Use `\n` in the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the answer you linked to. The answer states:

> If you wish to have a string which spans multiple lines, you may insert a backslash character '`\`' just before you terminate the line, like so:
>
> ```
> //Perfectly valid code
> var foo = "Bob \
> is \
> cool.";
> ```
>
> However that string will **not** contain `\n` characters in the positions where the string was broken into separate lines. The only way to insert a newline into a string is to insert a character with a value of 10, the easiest way of which is the `\n` escape character.
>
> ```
> var foo = "Bob\nis\ncool.";
> ```

So this is what you should be doing instead:

```js
//Perfectly valid code
var foo = "Bob\nis\ncool.";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('pre').textContent = foo;
});
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

If you want *both* to break the string into multiple lines *and* to have newlines within the string, you need both:

```js
//Perfectly valid code
var foo = "Bob\n\
is\n\
cool.";
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('pre').textContent = foo;
});
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
// template literal syntax
var foo = `Bob 
is 
cool.`;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('pre').textContent = foo;
});
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: I like it! I did see that in the [answer by DRS David Soft](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40334713/1575353)

Comment: Ah, I should have scrolled down haha