# escape double inverted quotes jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I escape double qoutes. even try '\' but in console it look bad. that why its not working

```
var vimeo;

'      <span class="play-button button" data-vimeo-id="'+ vimeo +'" data-vimeo-iframe="<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/'+ vimeo +'?dnt=1&amp;app_id=122963" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" title="bla bla" allow="autopla; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>" Play </span>'
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: You could use back ticks, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56580785/4051471

Comment: Quotes should be escaped as `&#34;` or `&quot;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Typescript template strings](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/template-strings.html), assuming the iframe string is just to retrieve at a later time (use `decodeURIComponent`):

```js
var vimeo;
var iframe = encodeURIComponent('<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + vimeo + '?dnt=1&amp;app_id=122963" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" title="bla bla" allow="autopla; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
var s = `<span class="play-button button" data-vimeo-id="${vimeo}" data-vimeo-iframe="${iframe}"> Play </span>`;
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = s;
document.body.append(element);
console.log(decodeURIComponent(document.getElementsByClassName('play-button')[0].getAttribute('data-vimeo-iframe')))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    var vimeo;

`<span class="play-button button" data-vimeo-id="${vimeo}" data-vimeo-iframe="<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/${vimeo}?dnt=1&amp;app_id=122963" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" title="bla bla" allow="autopla; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>" Play </span>`
```

Comment: kindly check the output , as in output its escaspe all the '//' as well

Comment: @faisaljanjua Could you provide me a link to the project?